# Get cell data using handsontable

Tags: javascript, postgresql, grid, handsontable

I'm looking for insert data in my postgre database from a handsontable data grid. So, I created my grid and it works but now, I don't know how to use methods like "getData" or "getDataAtCell" to get what the user will insert.

Here is the code :

```
<div id="example" class="excel"></div>
    <script>

    var data = [
                ["LastName", "FirstName", "Age", "Height"],
                ["", "","" ,""  ]

              ];

              var container = document.getElementById('example');
              var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: data,
                minSpareRows: 1,
                rowHeaders: true,
                colHeaders: false,
                contextMenu: true
              });   
    </script>


    <!--  <a href="#" id="valider">Submit</a>-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_button">Submit</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_button').click(function(){
            //alert ("test");

            //getDataAtCell(1,1);

            <?php 
                //$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=ita2015 user=postgres password='1234'";
                //$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

                //$sql = "INSERT INTO test_perso.etudiant(id_etudiant, nom_etudiant) 
                //        VALUES('5', ".data[1][0].");";
                //$res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");


                //echo data[0][0];
            ?>
            var temp;

            temp = $("#example").handsontable('getCell', 0, 0);
            alert(temp);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

I would probably look at the documentation to figure out how to use those two methods. Essentially, those methods are available to you using the `hot` instance so something like `hot.getDataAtCell(0,0)` will return to you the data at position 0,0. You could also use `hot.getData()` which returns the entire data array.